# Rails controller test: Get with query params aren't encoded properly

Tags: testing, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following line in my controller test:

`get brands_url, params: { test: 1, test2: 2}, as: :json`

I want to test the api request `brands?test=1&test1=2`.

In the controller index method, the params objects ends up looking like:

`<ActionController::Parameters {"{\"test\":1,\"test2\":2}"=>nil, "controller"=>"brands", "action"=>"index", "format"=>"json", "brand"=>{}} permitted: false>`

The params hash is being converted to json and interpreted as a key.

If I remove the `as: :json` option, I get what I think should be the expected behaviour:

`<ActionController::Parameters {"test"=>"1", "test2"=>"2", "controller"=>"brands", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>`

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
brands?test=1?test1=2
```

Is not a valid url. Try changing the second `?` to `&`.

```
brands?test=1&test1=2
```

Comment: I'm actually not explicitly using that url/query string, I was just showing it as a sample of the type of request that would be generated when using the `get` method (that simulates the request). I've correct the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the params in the params hash, I instead had to pass the parameters into to the url helper `brands_url`. So the following worked:

`get brands_url(test: 1, test2: 2), as: :json, xhr: true`

According to the rails documentations, the original technique should have worked though.